# Excel array to 2D python list

Tags: python, excel, list, dictionary

So I have to create a list in Python using two excel spreadsheets that have been provided (that show a list of names, locations, salaries, etc...) for a mock company employee info list. I am required to turn it into a 2D python list.

I believe I have the code down right, but I keep geeting an error due to the `x =+ 1'. Am I missing something?

```
def location_dict():
    f2 = open("Hw#5_Locations.csv", "r")
    dict1 = {}
    for b in f2:
        c = b.split(",")
        dict1[c[0]] = c[1]
        print("dict1", dict1)
    f2.close()
    return dict1

f1 = open("Hw#5_Employees.csv", "r")
x = 0
salary = []
ID_Salary = []
dict2 = location_dict()
for aline in f1:
    aline = aline.replace('\n','')
    values = aline.split(",")
    print(values[0], values[5])

    salary.append([values[0],values[1],values[2],values[5],values[7]])

    if x > 0:
        print("Salary[",x,"]", salary[x][0], salary[x][1], dict2[salary[x]    [2]])

    print("======= end line:", x)

    x =+ 1
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Syntax is wrong, Its `x += 1`.  `x =+1` will just keep setting x to 1

Comment: hmm... still didn't work... Do I need a `dict2 = {}` or something? I don't have a key for it...

Comment: You should also edit your question: you don't have excel spreadsheets, you have two text files, comma-separated values (which Excel can open and show like a worksheet).  Actually importing from a worksheet (which is saved in a proprietary format) or directly from Excel is a much more complicated problem.

Comment: what is the error that you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module. The defaults of `csv.reader` will read CSV files in Excel dialect:

```
import csv

with open('Hw#5_Employees.csv', 'r') as f:
    c = csv.reader(f)
    data = list(c)

# do something with data
```

You can also [read the data into a dictionary structure](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader), so that you can access columns by name.